# Manage javadoc to use jdk 1.7

Tags: java, linux, javadoc

I am trying to generate the documentation of a project written in java 7.
I have used things of java 7 like the try with resource statement, and when I try to generate the documentation of my project:

```
javadoc -d mydocks truckingCompany
```

(truckingCompany is the directory containing all java files)
I get a lot of syntax errors.If I try to compile the project using javac 1.7 I don't get all these errors.So I'm pretty sure that these errors are dued to the fact that javadoc is still using the version 1.6 of javac.How to change the version?

PS: An example of error is this:

```
home/ramy/Desktop/./truckingCompany/TCUtil.java:175: not a statement
catch( IOException | ClassNotFoundException | ClassCastException e)
      ^
```

All thing that are correct in Java 7.

Comment: What does `javadoc -J-version` give you?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.13) (6b20-1.9.13-0ubuntu1~10.10.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Did you perhaps compile using an IDE? I can't figure how it's possible that your `javac` is Java 7 but your `javadoc` is Java 6, otherwise.

Comment: Yes' I've used an IDE, but it's an university project and I need to generate the documentation without any IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javadoc is not a standalone program, but a part of the java development kit (JDK) (it's included in tools.jar.) This being said, you'll need to update your runtime environment to be Java 7 instead of Java 6.

Since you're running Linux, this *should* be as simple as pointing `/usr/bin/java` to your JDK 7. `java -version` should return Java 7 (or similar) to indicate this is correct.

Comment: javadoc is only contained in the JDK, not the JRE.